# Gnuplot dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXpm.4.dylib on Mac

Tags: gnuplot

I had a previous version of XQuartz on my Mac High Sierra 10.13.6 and I was running gnuplot (not very recent version, 4...). Then I updated XQuartz and gnuplot does not start anymore. I receive the lines

```
%gnuplot
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXpm.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /sw/bin/gnuplotx
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/X11/lib/libXpm.4.dylib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    /usr/X11/lib/libXpm.4.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
    /opt/X11/lib/libXpm.4.dylib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
/sw/bin/gnuplot: line 6:  1430 Abort trap: 6           /sw/bin/gnuplotx "$@"
```

I tried to follow the suggestion at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6616720 and I launched

```
sudo ln -s /opt/X11 /usr/X11
sudo ln -s /opt/X11 /usr/X11R6
```

After the first line it asks the password and it seems to have gone through. When I launch the second line X11R6, the answer is

```
ln: /usr/X11R6/X11: File exists
```

After this attempt, gnuplot does not start yet. Should I re-install XQuartz?

Comment: re-installing xquartz may help to solve the problem